# Can't reach global variables from typescript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, typescript

I'm currently working with an mvc-project. The project has been outsourced so I haven't written the code myself.

My mission is to convert one of the Javascript to a Typescript to begin with. The problem is that when I put my code in the ts-file I can't reach the global variables. Visual Studio just says that "the property does not exist on type window".

My .ts-file:

```
window.location.href = window.Search.URL_Searchfiles;
```

Some of them are located in .cshtml files between script tags and they use razor to set the variables.

The .cshtml-file:

```
<script>var Search = { URL_Searchfiles: '@Url.Action("Files", "Search")' }</script>
```

I've tried to declare the variables in the Typescript but I can't seem to get it right.
How do i reach global variables from a Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to extend the `Window` interface to add a `Search` element to it:

```
interface Window {
    Search: any;
}

window.location.href = window.Search.URL_Searchfiles;
```

Interfaces in TypeScript are open-ended, so you can keep binding new members to a particular object via it's interface.